# telescope-nvim & nvim-web-devicons: icons cut off in fuzzy finder

Tags: neovim, konsole

I've been using the `telescope.nvim` neovim plugin for a while. Recently I also installed the `nvim-web-devicons` plugin to better recognize filetypes when searching.

My problem is that the devicons look like this:
[image]
They are truncated/cut off on the right.

I'm:

- on Linux
- using KDE Konsole as terminal app
- using `Fira Code Nerd Font` 9pt

Answer (score 1):

Use a monospaced font

Here's how it looks on [FiraMono Nerd Font Mono](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/blob/master/patched-fonts/FiraMono/Regular/complete/Fira%20Mono%20Regular%20Nerd%20Font%20Complete%20Mono.otf) (link to .otf font download on GitHub):
[image]

In KDE Konsole:

1. Right click inside the terminal and click "Edit Current Profile"
   [image: List item]
2. Go to the "Appearance" tab on the left, then change your font by clicking the "Choose..." button
   [image]